# Export database in CSV format in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Edited the question as per the answer:

I'm using this command line and generated a CSV but I got 0 exports:

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db schooldbs --collection name --type=csv --out text.csv --fields name,email,mobile,city,birthday,createdAt
```

I got this response:

```
2019-12-24T07:28:16.382+0000    connected to: localhost
2019-12-24T07:28:16.386+0000    exported 0 records
```

What is `name` in that command line? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `mongoexport` inside mongo terminal. It should not be the case. You have to run from external(point o where mongoexport is there) if its installed globally means just execute the above command. Also replace placeholder like `dbname` us your real dbname and try.

**EDIT**

change `--collection name` name to your real collectionname

Comment: What is `collectionname` and how do I got about finding out? I'm new to mongo and don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: @Elaine Byene see what are all the collections in `schooldbs`, its like tables in RDBMS. Connect to your mongoDB and see what are the collections are there in db.